# Cakephp not changing selected value from Dropdown to default value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm not a veteran in CakePHP and Javascript, so I'm having trouble with a code.

What I'm trying to do is to creat a dropdown list using Formhelper. There is a value that shows another list (ex: value 1). If I choose "Value 1", a second dropdown list will appear, and if I select another value from the first list, the second dropdown list will not appear.

So far so good, this is working. The problem is that if I choose another option from the first list to hide the second list, when I display the second list again it won't reset the second list option.

How can I reset the selected option to the empty option in the secondList everytime I call the onChange in the firstList?

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSecondList(field) {
        switch (field.val()) {
           case 'value1':
              $('#divSecondList').show();
              $('#secondList').val("");
           break;
           default:
              $('#secondList').val("");
              $('#divSecondList').hide();
       }
    }
</script>

<div>
   <?php $this->Form->input('firstList', array(
            'label' => 'firstList',
            'type' => 'select',
            'empty' => '- select -',
            'options' => array(
                            'value1' => 'value1',
                             'value2' => 'value2'
            ),
            'onChange' => 'showSecondList($(\'#firstList\'));'
          ));
   ?>
  </div>

<div id="divSecondList" style="display:none">
   <?php echo $this->Form->input('secondList', array(
            'label' => 'secondList',
            'type' => 'select',
            'empty' => '- select -',
            'options' => array(
                            'value1' => 'value1',
                            'value2' => 'value2'
            ),
         ));
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It should work, just make sure you echo the first select: `<?php echo $this->Form->input('firstList', array(...`

Comment: Your javascript will always select the option with empty value in secondList, no matter what option you select in firstList. What is not working?

Comment: oh, it was a typo error the absence of "echo". I'll edit it.

Ip1051, I really don't know because I thought it should do this, but it is not selecting the empty option. I've tried to get all the options from the secondList using jQuery to see if it has indeed all options, but it only shows the option selected when secondList is showing.

example:
   If I select value2 in the secondList and change the option from the firstList to not show the secondList. When I get all the options from the secondList it only shows the value2, not every option.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be JavaScript issue rather than Cake, so let me rewrite it as simple HTML and JavaScript, so that you can test it's working as you want. If it doesn't in your code, is it possible you have some other JavaScript attached to those selects? Or do you see any errors in console?

```js
    function showSecondList(field) {
      switch (field.val()) {
        case 'value1':
          $('#divSecondList').show();
          $('#secondList').val("");
          break;
        default:
          $('#secondList').val("");
          $('#divSecondList').hide();
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="firstList">firstList</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select name="data[firstList]" id="firstList" onchange="showSecondList($('#firstList'));">
        <option value="">- select -</option>
        <option value="value1">value1</option>
        <option value="value2">value2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="divSecondList" style="display:none">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="secondList">secondList</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select name="data[secondList]" id="secondList">
        <option value="">- select -</option>
        <option value="value1">value1</option>
        <option value="value2">value2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dude thanks for the help, but I really can't get why this problem is happening. It is not getting any errors if I debug it, the javascript is ok (source, type, etc), and there is some strange behavious (I think,but I'm not veteran with js). The thing is that if I create a loop in any of the selects to get the options values and push into an array to show in alert, it is only showing the selected value (using something like this):
field = document.getElementById("firstList"); for (i = 0; i < field.options.length; i++) { fieldarray.push(field.options[i].innerHTML); alert(fieldarray[i]); }

Comment: Another possible reason is that you have more than one element with `id="firstList"` on current page that is not a select. Try to open dev console and search for it (better to search in console rather than in page source, if you're creating some HTML on fly).